# Different of input start with colon and without colon

Tags: jquery

What is the different between

```
$("input[name='ABC']") // without ":"
$(":input[name='ABC']") // with ":"
```

both work same to me, 
so should we write it with colon ":" or without?
which is more correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`input` will just select specifically the `<input>` element.

[`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selects `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, and `<button>`.

Comment: oh i see, so far i only work with <input>, did not work on others as you mention above, thanks